# Texting without the chain of previous conversations

Tags: text

How can I send a text to someone without all of our previous texts attached and without deleting the previous conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Neither text nor iMessages send the conversation history; that is saved locally on your own device, & also on theirs. Each user is in charge of whether or not to keep that history.

To send a text/iMessage, all you need is their phone number, nothing else. They don't even have to be in your address book.